# RabbitMQ Plugin Dependencies

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'm setting up a special ubuntu vm for rabbitmq plugin development. I am working through the plugin development guide here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html

The metronome plugin is working, so I wanted to get the rabbitmq_management plugin working as well.

I set up the necessary symlinks and when I run rabbitmq-plugin enable rabbitmq_management, I get the following error in the console:

```
 % ../scripts/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
Error: The following dependencies could not be found:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
```

I don't know where to put these dependencies (mochiweb, webmachine) so the rabbitmq_management (or it's dependencies) can see them.

I have tried to clone from git and make those projects directly in the rabbitmq-server/plugins directory with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plugins depend on other plugins. In this case you need the mochiweb and webmachine plugins. Place them inside the broker plugins folder

Comment: I cloned mochiweb and machine in the plugins dir and it worked. although when I cloned mochiweb, it still said both were needed. thanks alvaro

Comment: actually the rabbitmq-public-umbrella already comes with a mochiweb and webmachine wrapper/plugin so you'd better use those since they have patches to work with rabbitmq.

Comment: ok cool. I think I tried copying those into the plugins folder. or probably not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

> Error: The following plugins could not be found: 
>   RabbitMQ_management

After a long period, of reinstall, remove and reinstall.  The solution is simply that the plugin name is case sensitive.  Therefore, check the plugin directory for the correct case.  Simply changing the command from:

```
RabbitMQ-plugins enable RabbitMQ_Management
```

to

```
RabbitMQ-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

solved my issue.